# Programa em C que lê um ficheiro de texto e faz print das linhas por ordem inversa

Tags: c, string, memória, text

Gostaria de saber porque ao rodar o script abaixo, as linhas aparecem espaçadas, **exceto** a primeira linha.

**Input**

```
Linha1
Linha2
Linha3
Linha4
```

**Output esperado**

```
Produtos:
- Linha3
- Linha4
- Linha2
- Linha1
```

**Output obtido**

```
Produtos:
- Linha1-Linha 2
- Linha3
- Linha4
```

**Código**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>   

typedef struct linha {
  char *produtos;
  struct linha *prev;
} linha;

FILE *file;   
int main() {

  linha *tail = NULL;
  file = fopen("text.txt","r");
  char linha1[255];

  while (fgets(linha1,255,file)!=NULL) {
    linha *l1 = malloc(sizeof(linha));
    l1->produtos = malloc(strlen(linha1)+1);
    strcpy(l1->produtos,linha1);
    l1->prev = tail;
    tail = l1;
  }

  linha *current;
  current = tail;
    printf("Produtos:\n");
  while (current != NULL) {
    printf("- %s",current->produtos);
    current = current->prev;
  }
  return 0;

}
```

Comment: Porque o output esperado é `3,4,2,1` e não `4,3,2,1` ?

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, é bom você fazer um *cast* para o retorno de `malloc()`, pois em alguns compiladores pode não compilar, o meu por exemplo.
Ficaria assim:

```
linha *l1 =(linha*) malloc(sizeof(linha));
l1->produtos =(char*) malloc(strlen(linha1)+1);
```

Vou considerar que o output esperado é

```
Produtos:  
- Linha4  
- Linha3  
- Linha2  
- Linha1
```

Isso acontece porque na última linha do arquivo de texto não tem um `\n` e sim o EOF. Por isso, ele não dá a quebra-de-linha. Se quiser testar, dê um enter na última linha do seu arquivo de texto, você vai ver que agora ele vai estar "printando" de maneira correta.

Comment: não tinha pensado nisso, obrigado! já agora, gostaria de meter um ";" após cada linha, já experimentei sizeof(linha)-1 mas aparece sempre no inicio, antes do "-"